Options for using custom PHP in a wordpress site? No FTP access
My professional background is backend engineering, but I volunteered to help a nonprofit, and their website runs on wordpress, so I wrote some php that solves a problem for them, which I tested by running locally (via https://localwp.com/).
I had planned to get this code onto their live website, and recommendations that I've found online suggest uploading the php via ftp, using it to create a new template, and making a wordpress page using that template.
My problem is that the nonprofit I'm talking to doesn't know much about their wordpress instance, and their webmaster has been very noncommunicative, and I'm not sure how much he knows about wordpress beyond what he can access in the admin UI.
Besides FTP uploading, what options do I have to implement custom php in a wordpress site? I have an admin login.
Sorry to be verbose, thanks in advance!

There's a whole site devoted to Wordpress: [wordpress.se]. That's probably a better place to ask WP specific management issues.

thank you! stackoverflow was just the first thing I could think of, thanks for pointing me over there instead!

If you have the WordPress login details, you can use the File Manager plugin to upload the files. But it's a little unsafe because if something goes wrong the website might go down so you need FTP login details to fix it. I recommend requesting them to give you Cpanel login details or their hosting login details to upload all your files via Cpanel.

awesome, thank you, I'll look into what they currently have set up and ask them for Cpanel login details, as you said!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
